# How to search for numbers in consecutive using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tables like this

```
Period           ID       Amount

2015-04-01       01       500

2015-04-01       02       600

2015-05-01       01       500

2015-05-01       02       700

2015-06-01       01       700

2015-06-01       02       800
```

The date format is in : `yyyy-MM-dd`

I want to select the ID under the condition of different Period from April - June, and the amount increasing consecutively for 3 months.

For example, for the ID : 02 where the number increasing for 3 times from 600 to 700 to 800. For the ID : 01 is not being taken into account because the numbers are not increasing consecutively for 3 times, because for the ID : 01 doesn't increase from April to May, 500 and 500 again.

The result I need is to select the ID, the sample of the result would be :

```
ID
====
02
```

I really need help. Been thinking of this for weeks. Thank You

Comment: Have you tried any query?

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy with simple query and you will need some user defined variable in sql to do the calculation. Here is a way

```
select
ID from (
  select
  ID,
  Amount,
  @rn:= if(
     @prev_id = ID 
     and @prev_amt <> Amount 
     and ( timestampdiff(month,@prev_day,Period) = 1 ),
    @rn+1,1) as rn,
  @prev_day:= Period,
  @prev_id:=ID,
  @prev_amt:=Amount
  from test,(select @prev_id=null,@prev_day=null,@prev_amt:=0,@rn:=1)x
  order by ID,Period
)x 
where x.rn = 3
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/68b69/3

Comment: thanks. it works !! One more thing I need to ask. What if I want to add a parameter that the increasing value is 10% higher than the before value ? for example the ID: 01 has amount 600 in April and 700 in May so it meets the criteria. But in the case that the amount in May is only 650 then it doesn't meet the criteria. In which part of your query should I change if I need to add that parameter ?

Comment: You need to add that in the if condition , `@prev_amt` will contain the previous amount and the `Amount` is the current value and you can check the arithmetic operation there.

Comment: I still can't find the rightest query. Can you help me with it ?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/371a5b/1, for `ID : 02` on `2015-06-01` it got increased to `750` from `700` in `2015-05-01` is is less than 10% hence no data is selected. Let me know if this helps.